# How to use "&nbsp;" in HTML5

Tags: html

In HTML using `&nbsp;` for space, I get one space in the output. If my requirement needs more spaces say 100, then how to make that tag efficient? Should I type `&nbsp;` 100 times?

Comment: you can try with css:`padding-left:25em or margin-left:25em`

Comment: Please send your jsFiddle code. So It will be more clear for us, what you want to do.

Comment: Use of non-breaking spaces to get indentation is not a good practice. Use CSS `text-indent` property instead.

Answer (score 6):

`&nbsp;` is generally used when you are intended to place a space. It is generally used when you are considering the design in terms of space a letter occupies.

If you want to vary space depending upon other factors, feel free to use padding and margin.

Comment: I was not using the terminator at the end that's why it was not working for me.
Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the comments, you should be using css for this. However, if you have to do it in html, use 'pre' tags:

```
<pre>hello       world</pre>  //prints with extra spaces in between
```

Comment: Or the CSS equivalent, `style="white-space: pre"`, which won't change the font like `<pre>` will.

Answer (score 1):

you will use directly `&nbsp;` (or) `&#160;` for needed places.
ex:

```
<img src="vj.jpg">&nbsp;<img src="ss.jpg">
```

the pictures displayed in sequence with space.

Answer (score 0):

`&nbsp` is a character entity that denotes a non-breaking or fixed space.
It`s used to create a space that will not break into a new line by word wrap.
Provide space the same as a regular space.

> Correct syntax :
> `&nbsp;` (must add a semi-colon at the end) is a character entity for a [non-breaking space](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/html-space-how-to-add-a-non-breaking-space-with-the-nbsp-character-entity/).

You can use it either inside the container tag or just after closing the tag:

```html
<!--Inside container tag-->
<p>Text&nbsp;Text</p>
```

```html
<!--After closing the tag-->
<button class="btn btn-primary">Start Game</button> &nbsp;
<button class="btn btn-danger">End Game</button>
```

This will provide one space between the buttons.[image] 
Without `&nbsp;` [image] 
We can use tons of `&nbsp;` :
for instance - `<p>Text&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Text</p>`

But we have a tag provided in HTML itself named as `<pre></pre>`
Using this we could have as much required space as we want between the text.
For instance:

```
<p>text&nbsp;&nbsp;text</p> //gives out 2 spaces.
<pre>text      text</pre>  //gives out the added spaces.
```